# Store json_decode in a session variable

Tags: php, json

I am using `json_encode` to display MySQL values on a table. I want to store a value from my `json_encode` into a `$_SESSION` variable.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../../dbconnect.php';
$result = array();
    foreach($_SESSION['prod'] as $value) {
        //echo $value;
        $rs = mysql_query("select products.product_name as 'product_name', products.product_desc as 'product_desc', order_details.unitcost as 'unitcost', order_details.unitsrp as 'unitsrp', order_details.quantity as 'quantity', order_details.commrate as 'comm', order_details.ma as 'ma', order_details.od_no as 'od_no', `sales-order`.`so-no` as 'sono' from products left join order_details on products.product_id = order_details.product_id left join `sales-order` on order_details.so_number = `sales-order`.`so-number` where order_details.od_no = '$value'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
            $result[] = $row;
        }
    }


    echo json_encode($result);
    $data=json_decode($result);
    $qty = $data->quantity;
    $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

?>
```

But its giving an error. And is also giving an error into my table. I am not sure if I should `encode` and then `decode` on the same page, I'm really new to json.

`Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\isys\purchasing\po-grid\get.php on line 16`

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\isys\purchasing\po-grid\get.php on line 17`

**EDIT:**

To explain further, the page where I display the table with the data, `po-grid.php`, calls the `get.php` data which has the code above. It displays this result:

```
[{"product_name":"LEN274357A","product_desc":"Lenovo TP SL400 CD1.86, 1GB, 160GB, DVDRW, DOS\r\n","unitcost":"0.00","unitsrp":"25000.00","quantity":"5","comm":"0.000","ma":"500.00","od_no":"63","sono":"ert"},{"product_name":"HP Pavillion TS 14-n039TU","product_desc":"3rd generation intel Core 13-3217u","unitcost":"0.00","unitsrp":"12000.00","quantity":"3","comm":"0.250","ma":"0.00","od_no":"64","sono":"ASo2"}]
```

The `po-grid.php` calls the `get.php` to get the data.

Problem is, I just customized this code from [here](http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php) (you can check out the link and test so that you understand what I'm saying) and I'm not really sure how the code calls the data from the `json_encode` to the form data for editing. I think they associate the `input` name to call the data when editing.

Example:

`<input name="quantity">` will display a textbox with the quantity value even without declaring it. But what I need is a dropdown with looping. `<select name=quantity>` doesn't realy work, it has the value but what I need is like this:

```
<select class="easyui-combobox">
    <?php 
    $qty = $_SESSION['qty']; //this is the part where it calls the variable needed which I'm not sure how to call
    for($x=$qty;$x!=0;$x--)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$x."'>".$x."</option>";  
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

If the `quantity = 5`, then the option should be `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`.

Comment: Why do you store that in $_SESSION?

Comment: I need that specific data in another page.

Comment: The data exists in your database. You can get it again

Comment: I really don't want to query again. And that's not how my code works. It's really hard to explain.

Comment: Ok, hard to tell without knowing the background but it sounds like a bad way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the json_encode.  You're just echoing it to the screen.

Try:

```
$encoded_results = json_encode($result);
echo $encoded_results;

$data = json_decode($encoded_results);
```

Comment: Tried it but it still errors: Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: :/  sorry, without access to the data, I can't really test it very well.  Could you post some sanitized test data?  Try `print_r(get_defined_vars());` before you echo out your json_encode($result);

Comment: Show us what your code look like when you use json_encode